# How to get custom section style using titlesec?

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, minipage, titlesec, colorbox

I am trying to design a custom section. My desire section will be something like this :

[image]

But I am unable to get the exact result. This is what I was trying :

[image]

Horizontal rule will be joined at the bottom of the section number box. Section number box width will be 60pt and it is fixed. Could you please help to getting my desire result. You can also do it from scratch if you have any easier and standard solution.

My code snippet :

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{0088FF}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{60pt}{%
        \colorbox{myBlue}{%
            \parbox[b][15pt][t]{60pt}{% height, width
                \vfill%
                \fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\centering\color{white}{\thesection}
                \vfill%
            }}}%
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{15pt}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-75pt}
    \vspace*{-10pt}%
    \color{myBlue}{\Large #1}
\end{minipage}\\%
\color{myBlue}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}
%
}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3mm}{-5mm}
```

Comment: Could you post a *full* code, starting with `\documentclass` and including some document body?

Comment: Also, may it happen that your section titles be multilined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will let you figure out the colour/sizing part of the problem but a simpler solution would be this one :

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ctable}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{60pt}X}
\centering\cellcolor{blue!25} \thesection & #1\\
\arrayrulecolor{blue!25}\specialrule{.25em}{-0.1em}{0em}
\end{tabularx}
%
}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Thanks a million! There is a small space at the starting point of the tabularx but I have fixed that using \hspace{-0.25em}

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you want with a simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{0088FF}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{\rlap{\color{myBlue}\rule[-6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}\colorbox{myBlue}{%
           \raisebox{0pt}[13pt][3pt]{ \makebox[60pt]{% height, width
                \fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\color{white}{\thesection}}
            }}}%
{15pt}%
{ \color{myBlue}#1
%
}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3mm}{5mm}

\begin{document}

\section{heading on level 1 (section)}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me