# Recreating this chapter style in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, titlesec, books, book-design

I would like to recreate the following chapter style in LaTeX, where the '1' here is the chapter number. How do I go about doing this? I would've provided a base code but I have absolutely no idea how to start. 
[image]

Comment: The only package I've used for chapter style change was [fncychap](https://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap). But I don't know how much you can customize it.

Comment: It is easy to do with `titlesec`.

Comment: Hi wrb98,
this discussion could help you a lot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483919/how-to-get-custom-section-style-using-titlesec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short code with `titlesec` and `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\colorlet{headingcolor}{SkyBlue!60!SteelBlue}
\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filright\sffamily}
{\tcbset{height=13pt}\mbox{\tcbox[colframe=headingcolor,colback=headingcolor] {\hspace*{16mm}}\enspace \LARGE\textsf{\thechapter}}\\{\color{headingcolor}\titlerule[2pt]}}
{-1ex}
{\huge}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{CHAPTER TITLE}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]