# How to make custom section title placement and size

Tags: titlesec

I'm looking to make a custom section title similar to this but I can't figure out how to change the section number placement as well as aligning the horizontal line with the bottom of the section number. I'm using titlesec but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) for your current document setup for us to work on.

Comment: @maltebsa please see if the answer meets the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0pt}{\hfill}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0em} %left
{0em} %before
{1em} %after/below
\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    This is some regular text.
\end{document}
```

**edit to conform better to OP requirement**

adapted from --

[How to get custom section style using titlesec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483919/how-to-get-custom-section-style-using-titlesec)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ctable}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lC}
       \multirow{-2.5}{*}{\fontsize{70}{30}\selectfont\normalfont\thesection} & #1\\\arrayrulecolor{red!50!black}\cmidrule[4pt]{2-2}
    \end{tabularx}
    %
}
\begin{document}
    \section {Introduction}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your example. It does however seem like it is clashing with my subsections, subsubsuctions and my paragraph. This is how I define them:

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

Should I edit them to fit with the [explicit]{titlesec}? It seems like it is the cause since I'm normally only using the normal {titlesec}

Comment: I suggest you accept the answer given above if it meets the question in its present form

The additional compatibility with sub sub sections can then be taken up as a separate question

Comment: This is the same reason the site advertises that the question should be framed correctly to avoid this type of confusion
Since the question was limited the answer is also limited to the context of the question

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the confusion. You have helped me greatly. Have a blessed day.