# Thick line to the right and thin line below section of section title

Tags: titlesec

I am trying to customize the section title of an exercise book I am writing. The sections are numberless. I would like to get something like this:

## EXERCISES ################################

My question is rather different from the one posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483919/how-to-get-custom-section-style-using-titlesec), because I want the color box to the right of the section name. On the other hand, the solution proposed there cannot be permutes straightforward.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get custom section style using titlesec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483919/how-to-get-custom-section-style-using-titlesec)

Comment: Not exactly. I am want to reverse the behavior of the blue box and the section title.

Comment: The point is that it (hopefully) points you to the right direction. Once you identify which package offers the feature that you want, it's only a matter of reading its documentation to get the expected result.

Comment: @close voters: while titlesec probably is the solution, the proposed duplicate is rather different from the current question. I think it should not be closed as a duplicate of that question, maybe we can try to find a duplicate that is a bit closer to the current requirement.